# Sort and set for no repeated section

Tags: python, list, key, set

```
List = ["Wednesday_A_20", "Tuesday_C_22", "Thursday-A-30"]
```

i can sort this as

```
List.sort(key=lambda x: x.split("_", 1)[-1])
```

but is it possible to use

> set()
>   and get a desired output as

```
"Wednesday_A_20", "Tuesday_C_22"
```

shouldn't be any repeated letters in section 1.
New to python any better way ??? Thanks in advance

Comment: it seems that You have mix up "-" and "_"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can do

```
In [1]: mylist = ["Wednesday_A_20", "Tuesday_C_22", "Thursday_A_30"]

In [2]: key = lambda s: s.split('_')[1]

In [3]: from itertools import groupby

In [4]: [next(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(mylist, key=key), key=key)]
Out[4]: ['Wednesday_A_20', 'Tuesday_C_22']
```

A set is not *directly* applicable here, because it's only a section that is unique and not the whole string. You could use a dict though.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need things sorted once at the end, you're probably best off using a dictionary, where the keys are the A, C, etc. and where the values are Wednesday_A_20, etc.  Then at the end, get the dict.keys() and sort them.

If you need things sorted by key each step of the way, you still use the same keys and values as above, but instead of a dict you use a treap (http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/treap/) or red-black tree (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/red-black-tree-mod).  Both (can) work like dictionaries, except their keys are always kept in order, and they're a bit slower than dictionaries (but not slower than sorting dictionary keys inside a loop!).  Treaps are faster on average (nice for batch applications), but red-black trees have a lower standard deviation (nice for interactive applications).